# when touch back button on android how to move to another scene in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

A game created by cocos2dx. In active scene, when I touch the back button on android, how can i quit it! can give same example?.I am wrote this code inside the constructor. 
and i want that if i pressed the back button key in android it move to the another scene , can anybody send me the sample code,this my code it should move to the MainmenuScene, but not moving.

```
auto _keyListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
      _keyListener->setEnabled(true);
      _keyListener->onKeyReleased =     CC_CALLBACK_2(Jig_GameLayer::onKeyReleased, this);
    _eventDispatcher-   >addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(_keyListener, this);


void Jig_GameLayer::onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event*   unused_event)
{   if(keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_BACK)
    {
       Director  :: getInstance()->replaceScene( TransitionCrossFade::                 create(1.0f ,MainmenuScene::create()));     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in init():

```
this->setKeyboardEnabled(true);
```

create function:

```
void MenuScene::onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event *event){
    if(keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_BACK){
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Then on "onBackPressed()" handle back button logic. Then you can also add some "visual" button on screen and call onBackPressed from it as well.

Also don't forget to add declarations in .h file:

```
virtual void onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event *event);
void onBackPressed();
```